# $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is returning a different value after a rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I've done lots of googling, tried different stuff, but I still haven't figured out why my $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] gets changed. I think It has something to do with this line

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ D:/data/v5.3/%1/%2/$1 [L]
```

When visiting http://test.example.com the output of

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?> is "D:\data\v5.3\test\www"
```

When visiting http://test.redesign.example.com and http://test.code.example.com the output of

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?> is "D:/data"
```

Path:

```
d:\data\v5.3\test\
```

Folder structure:

```
- code
- redesign
- www
```

This is what I have in my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_vhost_alias.c>
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot "D:/data/v5.3/%1/www"

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)\.(code|redesign|new|old)\.(.*)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ D:/data/v5.3/%1/%2/$1 [L]

    <Directory "D:/data/v5.3">
      AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

When visiting http://test.example.com the output of

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?> should be "D:\data\v5.3\test\www" (this is fine)
```

When visiting http://test.redesign.example.com or 
http://test.code.example.com the output of

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?> should be "D:\data\v5.3\test\redesign" or 
"D:\data\v5.3\test\code" (depending on what's in URL after test.)
```

**note**:

```
dirname(__FILE__) is working just fine, so it's only an issue 
with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] which some of my websites might rely on
```

Comment: By input you mean output, don't you?

Comment: Oops! My bad, I'm going to edit my question. You are right, I mean output not input.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

in your ".htaccess" file.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a try. I created a new .htaccess in `d:\data\v5.3\test\code` which contained the code above but no luck. I'm still getting the same result